# GridBagLayout components in wrong position

Tags: java, image, containers, jbutton, gridbaglayout

My code is meant to but the JButton at the top but when I add a image it goes on top of the image which is good but instead of being at the top it is in the middle and you can't get a value for gridy so I don't know how to make it go to the top. I have got lots of buttons on the Container but I will just put the code for one to make it shorter but if you need full code I will provide it. Thank you Here is my code

```
public void add(Container pane){
setBackground(Color.black);

    pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

    URL resource = getClass().getResource("Graphitebackground.v2.jpg");

    ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon(resource);
    URL resource3 = getClass().getResource("Graphitebackground.v4.jpg");

    ImageIcon i3 = new ImageIcon(resource3);
    URL resource1 = getClass().getResource("Graphitebackground.v3.jpg");
    ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(resource1);  
    JLabel background = new JLabel(i2);
    background.setSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));

    background.setVisible(true);
    background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    JButton button;
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    //natural height, maximum width
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;           

    JButton label2 = new JButton(i1);

    c.weightx = 0.5;

    label2.setText("Level1");
    label2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    label2.setForeground(Color.RED);
    label2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,100));
    label2.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
    label2.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
    label2.setBorderPainted(false);
      label2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter(){
         public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){
            label2.setBorderPainted(true);
            label2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red,3)); 
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){
             label2.setBorderPainted(false); 
        }
        });
        background.add(label2,c);
        pane.add(background);
}
```

Comment: why are you using a `JLabel` as `background` and adding `label2` to it? why not using a `JPanel` instead? also you used `GridBagLayout` for `pane` but specified no constraint when adding `background` to it

Comment: Ok will change it but will that fix the problem

Comment: because i2 is a image icon and when i change it to JPanel i get an error

Comment: [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) and/or [JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) may help you